# PHP JSON getting specific value of each key

Tags: php, html, json

I have a php code that reads JSON files. Part of the JSON sample below:

```
 "Main": [{
    "count": 7,
    "coordinates": [89,77],
    "description": "Office",
  },{
    "count": 8,
    "coordinates": [123,111],
    "description": "Warehouse",
  }]
```

and I am trying to code PHP to only get the info (count, coordinates, description) of those who's description is included in the criteria like `Warehouse`. PHP Sample below

```
$validcriteria = array("Warehouse", "Parking_lot");
```

How do I do an if-statement to check first if "description" is included in the valid criteria. I tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work right.

```
$JSONFile = json_decode($uploadedJSONFile, false);
foreach ($JSONFile as $key => $value)
{
    if (in_array($key['description'] , $validcriteria))
    {
        #more codes here
    }
}
```

My code in PHP has been working except when I try to add `$key['description']` to try and check the description first if it's valid. My code above is reconstructed to remove sensitive information but I hope you got some idea of what I was trying to do.

Comment: You want to remove those commas from your json if they are there in the real feed, that trips up json_decode

Comment: No they are not there, I just copy-pasted part of the JSON contents since it's huge, and edited some areas. I just need help in that area where you can get the value of a key inside/within the huge JSON contents.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to understand the structure of a parsed JSON string, start with a `print_r($JSONFile);` to examine its contents. In your case, you will find that there is an outer key `'Main'` which holds an array of sub-arrays. You will need to iterate over that outer array.

```
// Set $assoc to TRUE rather than FALSE
// otherwise, you'll get an object back
$JSONFile = json_decode($uploadedJSONFile, TRUE);
foreach ($JSONFile['Main'] as $value)
{
  // The sub-array $value is where to look for the 'description' key
  if (in_array($value['description'], $validcriteria))
  {
    // Do what you need to with it...
  }
}
```

Note: if you prefer to continue setting the `$assoc` parameter to `false` in `json_decode()`, examine the structure to understand how the objects lay out, and use the `->` operator instead of array keys.

```
$JSONFile = json_decode($uploadedJSONFile, FALSE);
foreach ($JSONFile->Main as $value)
{
  // The sub-array $value is where to look for the 'description' key
  if (in_array($value->description, $validcriteria))
  {
    // Do what you need to with it...
  }
}
```

You might also consider using `array_filter()` to do the test:

```
$included_subarrays = array_filter($JSONFile['Main'], function($a) use ($validcriteria) {
  return in_array($a['description'], $validcriteria);
});
// $included_subarrays is now an array of only those from the JSON structure
// which were in $validcriteria
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I couldn't post the entire code I have, too many sensitive information and may take a while to do cover ups. But yes I have series of `foreach` statements before this section wherein I am having trouble. This page was already running until my boss told me not to include those other areas/buildings.

Comment: So given the 3 options I have above, one must work for you. In particular, the middle one which retains the original JSON strucutre (which would be objects, not arrays) checking `in_array($value->description, $validcriteria)`. Chiefly, you need to debug as you go with `print_r()` to understand the structure as you go.

Comment: I missed that middle one, it look's like what I was looking for, let me try that and get back to you.:)

Comment: Thanks, this worked exactly how I wanted. I didn't know I can do `$value->description` in `if (in_array($value->description, $validcriteria))`.:)

Comment: @Jay The first argument to `in_array()` can be any value to search in the second argument, even an array if the second argument is a 2D array. So yes, you may use anything that resolves to a scalar like `$value->description` (since `$value` is an object).

Comment: No, I meant I wasn't aware I can add a -> to a JSON Decode variable.:p So now I can have the option to not do Foreach and head straight to any sections in the JSON file I wanted.

Comment: @Jay If the structures inside the decoded JSON are objects (`stdClass`) as yours are, due to the `$assoc=false` parameter, then yes, you need to access them with `->`.

Answer (score 0):

Given your JSON structure, you probably want

```
foreach($decoded_json['Main'] as $sub_array) {
    if (in_array($sub_array['description'], $validation)) {
       ... it's there ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set false to second argument of json_decode function, it's returned as an object,
if you change it to TRUE, the code would work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

and you have to change key to value;

```
foreach ($JSONFile->Main as $key => $value)
{
    if (in_array($value->description, $validcriteria))
    {
        #more codes here

    }
}
```

this code assume your json file has one more depth greater than your example. that's why $JSONFile->Main in the foreach loop.

Comment: I'm afraid all of my PHP files that are already running are set to False in this part of the code, I think I encountered an error a while back and the solution provided was to either use False instead of true. Isn't there a way to do this in a FALSE version? Like perhaps `$key->description` instead of `$key['description']`?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it, and for json part, it's not valid json, check out json in here : http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score -1):

Try to use that :

```
if ( array_key_exists('description', $key) )
```

Comment: What does this do?:) What I'm trying to come up with is a way so PHP collects the info like `count` or `coordinates` or `description` but collect only if it's description (Warehouse or Office or Parking) is included in the array of allowed/valid criteria which is listed above. In my example above, only the 2nd record will be collected because it's `description` is `Warehouse` and `Warehouse` is included in the &validcriteria array.

Comment: This is simply checking if the first given parameter is a key of the 2nd parameter (which is the array).

I used that for a piece of code i had to write which is supposed to write some lines into a JSON file if the key doesn't exist, probably for the same thing as you.

It's really straight forward, have a look http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: Sorry, I did not put that -1 in this comment, somebody did :s Ah I understand now, this one is for checking if the key is included in that main key at all. Thanks, this is a good info I can use when debugging